# Error: Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, assembly-binding-redirect

Out of nowhere my ASP.NET MVC 4 solution gives me this error:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

I Googled the problem and everybody says it has happened when anyone updates the solution from one version to another. But I didn't update my solution, just change the IDE from VS12 to VS13. Is this what creates the problem?

The full stack trace is as follows:

> [TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated by type: System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.]
>      System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +0
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +30
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9971917
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath) +54
>      Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedRazorViewEngine.Microsoft.Web.Mvc.IViewEngineProxy.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath) +42
>      Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineFixWorker`1.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath) +57
>      Microsoft.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetPathFromGeneralName>b__0(String path) +66
>      System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, String virtualPath, Func`2 virtualPathExists) +90
>      System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__8(IDisplayMode mode) +66
>      System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +103
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +94
>      System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, IDisplayMode currentDisplayMode, Boolean requireConsistentDisplayMode) +297
>      System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, IDisplayMode currentDisplayMode) +108
>      Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineFixWorker`1.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations) +653
>      Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineFixWorker`1.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +1508
>      Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineFixWorker`1.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache) +329
>      Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedRazorViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache) +66
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e) +68
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) +182
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator) +110
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName) +329
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +135
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +230
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__17() +74
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +388
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +72
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +303
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +155
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651116
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Try removing the System.Web.Razor assembly binding in the web.config if present. (http://forums.asp.net/t/1968686.aspx?Installed+Nuget+package+Razor+Engine+whole+system+stops)

Comment: you are awesome. I just lost 6 hours on it. Thanks much. Problem resolved

Comment: Yes it works! - But why is this a problem in the first place?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi/@cuteteddy, you should add that as the answer if it was the correct one. That way, others know what the answer is...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From my friend  Claudio Redi's comment the solusion of this problem is:

Try removing the System.Web.Razor assembly binding in the web.config if present. http://forums.asp.net/t/1968686.aspx?Installed+Nuget+package+Razor+Engine+whole+system+stops

Comment: Why does the section keep getting added every time a new package is installed or one is updated? Why is this error happening in the first place? Anyone know?

Comment: When I do this, It says Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor'

Answer (score 15):

Go to Web.config and Search for the Assembly name="System.Web.Razor" and comment as follow.

```
 <!--<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>-->
```

After Commenting save and run the project,it will work fine.

Comment: And what you say about after publishing on remote host without full access? I did as you suggested and vote +1 to your answer, now I have a big problem with remote server!

Answer (score 3):

For me commenting of "System.Web.Razor" from web config did not worked.Here are the things i did to resolve this. 
Search your whole solution for references to MvcWebRazorHostFactory. you will find something like below in config file.

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Change Version=4.0.0.0 to Version=5.0.0.0 and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the binding redirect as suggested above worked for 3 of my older machines but did not work on a fourth, newer machine.

Turns out that commenting out the binding redirect apparently just allows System.Web.Razor version 1.0.0.0 to be found/used, but my 4th machine, a newly built machine, lacked System.Web.Razor.DLL version 1.0.0.0.

Copying System.Web.Razor version 1.0.0.0 DLL to that machine in the website's bin folder, then my problem was solved. Removing 1.0.0.0 version DLL and putting version 2.0.0.0 back, the problem returned.

Another discovery I made regarding the machines where the bindingRedirect approach did work was that once RazorEngine worked for me after having commented out the binding redirect, I could un-comment-out the binding redirect and RazorEngine continued to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your project references are in turn linked to different versions of Microsoft.AspNet.Razor library, that are incompatibles between them.

Your stack trace points to `System.Web.WebPages` dll, which is probably linking to a version of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor` older that the one referenced by other NuGet package (for example `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`).

**To fix the problem:**

1. If you are directly referencing the `System.Web.WebPages`, remove the reference and start using the `System.Web.WebPages` NuGet package
2. If you are already using the `System.Web.WebPages` NuGet package, update it to the same version of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor` package that you are already using in your project.

This will fix your current error, but probably will result in a new one appearing, especially if you are migrating or mixing packages between `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` versions. In this case, you need to sync the versions of all your NuGet packages related to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error "inheritance security rules violated by type" in a Windows Service that used WCF components.

The same service worked on other server, but in a specific one, it didn't.

What fixed this error was commenting the following line in the app.config file.

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
```

We took a lot to figure it out, hope it helps somebody.