# Website publish error in ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I published my ASP.NET MVC aplication to the Hostgator FTP Server. I got this error.

> **Server Error in '/' Application**
>
> *Inheritance security rules violated by type*

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576750/error-inheritance-security-rules-violated-by-type-system-web-webpages-razor-w ?

Comment: I dont have anything like system.web.Razor in my web.config.  If you look at the image I sent, its not talking about that

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read through this to write a Helpful Question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: rather than posting a screen shot: copy paste the text!